# Location of swagger.json when created with Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, azure-api-apps

When I build and run my Azure Web API I get a nice swaggerUI.

I want to add the API to Azure API Management.

For this I need either a URL or the swagger.json file.

Where does Swashbuckle put the file?

Or if it generates it on the fly, how can I get access to it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Swagger.json file should be accessible at [yourwebsitedomain]/swagger/docs/v1

There should also be a link to the swagger.json file at the top of the Swagger UI

Comment: Consider expanding on the route: "v1" is only if the configuration is set as such when configured using `c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "[yourwebsitedomain]");`

Comment: Is the swagger.json file never actually written to disk?  When running my API i can navigate to the JSON file through the webserver but there is no swagger.json file anywhere on the machine.

Comment: for a recent version (v2) this path should work:
'hostname/v2/api-docs'

Comment: It would appear that it is never written to disk. This github issue has more info, including some ways you might write the file to disk if desired: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/559

Answer (score 1):

there is a link to the swagger.json [image: link] on your page.

Answer (score 0):

For me the json was located at the URL:

http://[SERVER]:[PORT]/v1/swagger